# arguments problem help

Tags: c++, visual-c++, command-line, winapi, arguments

i have created a win32 window it work fine but im tryin to get command argument using lpcmdline. it works fine but when i try to compare it to string it to does work here is the comparing code

```
TCHAR checking[]=_T("hello"); 
if(args==checking) // args equals lpcmdline like this LPTSTR args=lpcmdline
{
    TCHAR greeting[]=_T("heys");
}
else
{
    MessageBox(NULL,args,L"1",MB_OK);
    /*if args doesn't equal checking tha cout what is inside args*/
    MessageBox(NULL,checking,L"2",MB_OK);
    //cout checking
}
```

well when i cout both varabiles they are the same like args output is hello and checking output is hello but i don't know why they don't get equaled please help
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not the right way to compare two strings in C++.

Given that you're comparing a `TCHAR` array with an `LPTSTR`, call [`_tcscmp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0z9k731.aspx) instead of using the `==` operator.

Answer (score 2):

`if(args==checking)` compares the *pointers* `args` and `checking`. Since they are pointing at different places the condition is not satisfied. What you want is a string comparison, for that you need to use function like `_tcscmp`.